# south, dry run, and transactions

Tags: django, django-south, data-migration

Can still run a data migration through a dry run and have it do all the data manipulations via the ORM API, but simply not commit (rollback) the transaction at the end?

I understand that there are potential portability issues.  For example, Postgres not doing DDL inside a transaction.  But if I want to, can I still somehow do the above?

Comment: Yes you can do that, but, out of curiosity, why would you want to do that?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/south-users/iIQT8ZWs2cI This is how you can reset the migrations

Comment: probably out of extra paranoia. I understand that errors will end up aborting and rolling back the transaction.  But I'm always paranoid about some non-error conditions (e.g. db warnings) that may not result in a rollback.

Comment: You dont have to be. From the documentation,  `--db-dry-run: Loads and runs the migration, but doesn’t actually access the database (the SQL generated is thrown away at the last minute). The migration is also not recorded as being run; this is useful for sanity-testing migrations to check API calls are correct.
`

Comment: I've always interpreted that as SQL is generated but not executed against the db, which is what I want to do.  For example, if I send the database a value that exceeds a field's size, some databases will truncate the value and only generate a warning.